# How do I use expressionHandler with authorizeHttpRequests?

Tags: spring-security

Since `authorizeRequests()` is deprecated, I had updated it to the new `authorizeHttpRequests()`. Since I did that, `expressionHandler` is throwing Unresolved Reference error. There is no need for screenshots, simply `authorizeRequests().expressionHandler(...)` works and `authorizeHttpRequests().expressionHandler(...)` throws unresolved reference. I already created the handler, now I just need to add it into the filterChain.